# Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, jbossfuse, fuseesb

Hi I am getting error when try to run camel project in fuse container

org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem:
 Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:quote-endpoints.xml] Offending resource: URL [bundle://251.0:0/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is        org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem:

Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]

Offending resource: OSGi resource[classpath:quote-endpoints.xml|bnd.id=251|bnd.sym=null]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from OSGi resource[classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml|bnd.id=251|bnd.sym=null]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: OSGi resource[classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml|bnd.id=251|bnd.sym=null] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Check your xml files and remove those CXF imports. They are no longer required for many years. eg look for anything with `META-INF/cxf/cxf.xm` and similar and remove those.

Comment: Hi Claus,
quote-endpoints.xml imports resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" /> please see below

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />

Comment: Yes remove  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />

Answer (score 0):

Yes - there are two xml files -

applicationContext.xml which imports quote-endpoints.xml

```
<import resource="classpath:quote-endpoints.xml" />
```

AND

quote-endpoints.xml impor resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" /> please see below

```
xsi:schemaLocation="
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
             http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring 
             http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
             http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf 
             http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
             http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration 
             http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of cxf in the POM.xml file.  Most probably, you may be having unsupported cxf version for the project.